# Istio AuthorizationPolicy for multiple services with same suffix

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have couple services in my namespace with common suffix to their labels and I would like to add the same Istio's AuthorizationPolicy to each (same rule, different source). I wonder if there is a way to write only one policy to all of them.
The easiest way would be if spec.selector.matchLabels would except regex but IIUC this is not supported.
Is there another way? Would adding a common label to the services would work? at what level that label should be? (service, deployment, pod) Thanks

Comment: So you want to apply the same AuthorizationPolicy rules to different workloads in your namespace that have a common label?

Comment: If that's possible,,, not sure how to apply common label to different workloads. Each deployment/service/pod already have its workload label.

Comment: As all of your services are in one namespace, have you tried to add authorization policy which applies to all workloads in this specific namespace? There is an example in istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/).